# Формирование запросов к данным таблицы, сравнение и вывод суммы

Tags: mysql

Прошу помочь с формированием запроса к таблице.
Совсем не понимаю SQL запросы, но встала задача вывести количество ответов на комментарии.
В таблице есть 2 столбца:

- id (id комментария)
- reply_to (со значением 0 - если это головной комментарий или данными id комментария, к которому он написан, если это ответ).
  Ответов 3-го порядка нет, т.е. не существует ответа на ответ.

Вопрос, как сформировать запрос, чтобы вывести сумму ответов к головному комментарию, т.е. собрать по каждому id головного комментария значения из reply_to, ему равные,  и суммировать их?

За наводку или ответы 500 плюсов в карму, независимо от вероисповедания и прочей антинаучной ерунды.

Comment: вложенность бесконечная?

Comment: Кол-во ответов не регламентируется, т.ч. да

Comment: как вложенность бесконечная, если *Ответов 3-го порядка нет, т.е. не существует ответа на ответ.* ?

Comment: сделайте если сможете тестовые данные сюда - http://sqlfiddle.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение на основе

> Ответов 3-го порядка нет, т.е. не существует ответа на ответ.

Тест на схеме

```
CREATE TABLE `items_comments` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `reply_to` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Запрос

```
select  c.id,
        (select count(*) from items_comments where reply_to= c.id ) as cnt
from items_comments c
where c.reply_to = 0
```

Не выводить записи при отсутствующих ответах (где `cnt = 0`)

```
select  c.id,
            (select count(*) from items_comments where reply_to= c.id ) as cnt
from items_comments c
where c.reply_to = 0
having cnt > 0
```

Comment: а таблица тут comments?

Comment: переименуй под свои требования

Comment: ну у меня вся таблица называется items_comments

Comment: переименовал таблицу в ответе.

Comment: запрос выведет список items_comments первого уровня и кол-во ответов.

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'c.id' in 'field list'

Comment: Значит в таблице `items_comments` нет поля `id`

Comment: Добавил схему в ответ

Comment: @Nikolay да, об этом стоит задать отдельный вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

```
select t1.id, count(1) cnt
   from items_comments t1 
      join 
        items_comments t2 
      on (t2.reply_to = t1.id) 
   where t1.reply_to = 0  
   group by id
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно еще дополнительно проверить, если вложенность все-таки есть, и нужны ответы только на головной комментарий.

```
SELECT reply_to AS id, COUNT(id) FROM comments WHERE reply_to != 0 AND reply_to IN (SELECT id FROM comments WHERE reply_to = 0) GROUP BY reply_to;
```

Comment: а таблица тут comments?

Comment: Кстати подзапрос IN вообще не нужен. условия reply_to!=0 достаточно что бы найти ответы

Comment: Да, таблица comments. Если у вас вложенности точно не будет, то подзапрос не нужен