# Использование mysql запросов в PHP

Tags: php, mysql

По стопам [Формирование запросов к данным таблицы, сравнение и вывод суммы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/515247/%D0%A4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%8B) 
Создали запрос к БД, он обрабатывается если напрямую в phpmyadmin запускать.
Вопрос, как его интегрировать в PHP

```
SELECT c.`id` , (
  SELECT COUNT( * ) 
  FROM  `items_comments` 
  WHERE  `reply_to` = c.id
) AS сount
FROM  `items_comments` c
WHERE c.`reply_to` = 0
```

Собственно сам запрос, но не обрабатывается, если вставить вот так:

```
public function ReplyCount($id) {
    global $mysql, $langArray;
    $mysql->query("

    SELECT c.`id` , (

    SELECT COUNT( * ) 
    FROM  `items_comments` 
    WHERE  `reply_to` = c.id
    ) AS сount
    FROM  `items_comments` c
    WHERE c.`reply_to` = '0'
    ");

    return true;
}
```

Где `ReplyCount` - значение, которое требуется вывести.
Как его оформить?

Comment: Объект $mysql что из себя представляет?

Comment: Если правильно понял global

Comment: Не совсем, ключевое слово global объявляет объект глобальным, чтобы вы могли получить к нему доступ из функции. А вот что за класс у этого объекта?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
public function ReplyCount($id) {
    global $mysql, $langArray;
    $result = $mysql->query("

    SELECT c.`id` , (

    SELECT COUNT( * ) 
    FROM  `items_comments` 
    WHERE  `reply_to` = c.id
    ) AS сount
    FROM  `items_comments` c
    WHERE c.`reply_to` = '0'
    ");
    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    return $row['count'];
}
```

Comment: Не работает, но мне кажется тут загвоздка как раз в неправильном указании c.id - я не очень понимаю, что это.